# issue with the using print function unable to print string

Tags: c, input

when the input is yes in status .the string s does not seem to be able to get printed.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {

    char name[20],sta[3];
    scanf("%s",&name);
    scanf("%s",&sta);
    if((strcmp("Yes",sta)==0)||(strcmp("yes",sta)==0))
        printf("Mrs.%s",name);
    if((strcmp("No",sta)==0)||(strcmp("no",sta)==0))
        printf("Ms.%s",name);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `sta[3]` is not big enough to hold the string "Yes". Make it `sta[4]`. Also, you shouldn't have the `&` before `name` or `sta` in the scanf.

Comment: You should add a newline at the end of the print format strings.

Comment: regarding: `scanf("%s",&name);` and `scanf("%s",&sta);`  1) in C, an array reference degrades to the address of the first byte in the array. It is an error to ask for the address of that array.  2) when using the input format specifiers '%s' and/or '%[...]' always use a MAX CHARACTERS modifier that is 1 less than the length of the input buffer because those specifiers always append a NUL byte to the input.  3) when calling any of the `scanf()` family of functions, always check the returned value (which is the number of successful input conversions)

Comment: OT: it is a very poor programming practice to include header files those contents are not used.  Suggest removing the statements: `#include <math.h>` and `#include <stdlib.h>`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have improved your code based on suggestions in comments.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {
    char name[20] = {0}, 
            sta[4] = {0};

    scanf("%s", name);
    scanf("%s", sta);

    if ((strcmp("Yes", sta) == 0) || (strcmp("yes", sta) == 0))
        printf("Mrs.%s\n", name);

    if ((strcmp("No", sta) == 0) || (strcmp("no", sta) == 0))
        printf("Ms.%s\n", name);

    return 0;
}
```

- First created `sta` of size 4 to allow 3 characters of "Yes" to fit in it along with `'\0'` terminator.
- `scanf()` doesn't require `&` operator for character strings.
- Initialized character array to `'\0'` (equivalent to ASCII 0).
- Removed not required header files and improved formatting a bit.